# The '/var/run/supervisor.sock' file is not being created when I use Supervisord

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon, supervisord

I'm running [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) on my Ubuntu 14.04 server and everything works fine. I deploy using a git push and upon deployment I also need to restart my application server ([gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)) which I can supposedly do using `supervisorctl`.

In my `supervisord.conf`, gunicorn is defined as follows:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/home/imb/imb/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -b 127.0.0.1:5000 -w 1 app:app
directory=/home/imb/imb
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/gunicorn.log
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
```

and I enabled `supervisorctl` like this:

```
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
```

I started supervisor using:

```
sudo supervisord -c /home/imb/imb/supervisord.conf
```

As far as I understand I now should be able to restart gunicorn using the command `supervisorctl restart gunicorn`, but when I do that I get

```
$ supervisorctl restart gunicorn
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

I checked and the file `/var/run/supervisor.sock` indeed doesn't exist, even though I'm sure supervisor is in fact running:

```
$ ps -A | grep supervisor
27211 ?        00:00:00 supervisord
```

Does anybody know why the `/var/run/supervisor.sock` file isn't created, even though supervisor is clearly running? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716159/nginx-and-supervisor-setup-in-ubuntu  Have you tried any of its oslutions? Do they work? If they do not, how do they fail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alright, after messing around some more I found what I did wrong.

Turns out the lines for `supervisorctl` below, only tell `supervisorctl` where it can find the socket file.

```
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock
```

Further above in the file there are two other lines which define where the file is actually created:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock
```

As you can see that created the socket file in `/tmp/` while `supervisorctl` tried to read it from `/var/run/`. I changed the last line to `file=/var/run/supervisor.sock` and now it works beatifully.

I hope this answer might help someone else dealing with the same trouble.

Also, you can check out the link provided by @MariusMatutiae in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716159/nginx-and-supervisor-setup-in-ubuntu

Comment: I see that the page I suggested did contain the right solution for you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/28469044/2796243   . I am glad to see I could help, cheers.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - Yes indeed, I might not have given you the recognition which you deserved. So a big thanks to you! Note that I'm still happy to give you the 50 bounty points. Just write an answer and I'll reward it to you.. :-)

Comment: Thanks, very nice of you, but I did not **really** find the solution. It's just that the page above contains several different solutions, only one of which (happily) applies to you, but it can be helpful to others reading this post to know that other solutions may be available, should the need arise. That's all. Cheers.

Comment: I faced another "funny" problem. Don't use tmp folder for socket file as it's cleaned automatically and socket file will be erased till next supervisord restart.

Answer (score 6):

For users who have the same entry for both

```
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock
```

&

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock
```

follow below steps to fix the problem -

1. Delete .sock file from /tmp
2. Run 'supervisord' command. This will recreate the sock file.
3. Run 'supervisorctl -i' to check the status of the services.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 3):

After too much struggling with this issue, with everybody telling me to just `enable` or `restart` which was not working. I finally found out the solution for me:

- First of all acknowledge that you have the main supervisor.conf file here: `/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf`
- If you are in my case, you also have a project specific `.conf` file in here: `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/project.conf`

Somehow `supervisorctl` was working fine but the weird thing is that doing `service supervisor restart` breaks everything and you get the error of OP.

The solution then is to:

1. Rename `project.conf` to `project.conf.tmp`
2. Then `service supervisor restart` (after what `supervisorctl` works again)
3. You rename back your project conf file to `project.conf`
4. `supervisorctl reread`, `supervisorctl update`, `supervisorctl restart all`

Answer (score 0):

vi /opt/conf/supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock

; rpc interface for supervisorctl
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock

[program:program1]
```

run supervisord

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /opt/conf/supervisord.conf
```

run supervisorctl

```
/usr/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/conf/supervisord.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that supervisord was running within a docker container. When I wanted to use the `supervisorctl` command the only response was `unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file`.

The solution to my problem was that I had to execute the `supervisorctl` command as the root.

`sudo supervisorctl`

No more `unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was missing log file mention in the `supervisor.conf` file

Fix:

```
touch /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured because a directory was missing in one of the config files for one of my programs.  Once I made the directory, supervisorctl started fine.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade it to MacOS Sierra **10.12.5**.

I faced the same issue and everything was right in the config file as well. Later I figured that I had moved to latest MacOS Sierra **10.12.3** and then it didn't work. It had been working on the older version but not at this specific version of MacOS. Then I upgraded it to MacOS Sierra **10.12.5** and everything seems to be working fine.