# Supervisor - unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file when nodeamon=true

Tags: linux, docker, supervisord

I have a problem with supervisor.

My supervisord.conf looks like:[unix_http_server]

```
file=/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///run/supervisor/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
```

When I try to start it using the command `service supervisor start`

I get info logs:

```
2022-06-29 14:59:59,884 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
2022-06-29 14:59:59,892 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2022-06-29 14:59:59,892 INFO supervisord started with pid 5774
```

but then when I run the command: `supervisorctl status` I get the info log: `unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file`

I try to switch to the `nodeamon=false` and it works as expected but I read then in the docker container it is recommended to use flag true.

I run my docker image in Azure App Service for Containers.

Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file](https://superuser.com/questions/1069276/unix-var-run-supervisor-sock-no-such-file)

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1069276/unix-var-run-supervisor-sock-no-such-file